# Generate new world exactly as intended in plugin

Tags: bukkit

I want to build a world in Minecraft then replicate it in code so when the world generates it builds an empty world with starting from the very bottom a layer 10 high of still water that goes on infinitely and then a structure built at exact coordinates. around 0,0 (I don't mind having to input block for block on the structure itself). I don't exactly understand how I would accomplish this, I want to override the default world gen completely. The goal of this is that once it's done i can just hand the plugin jar to someone and they can put it in their plugin folder and once the server starts it generates this world (I'd also like to maybe regenerate the world each time the server is loaded but not when the plugin is reloaded, cause i do that a lot) , thoughts? I've been searching for how to do this but I've been coming up short.

**update**

I have this much from a tutorial I followed (*watch?v=WsqTwUtubrg*) but I don't understand how to have it override the default generation. this is the code I have:

Main Class:

```
public ChunkGenerator getDefaultWorldGenerator(String worldname, String id){
    return new WorldGen(this);
}
```

WorldGen class:

```
public class WorldGen extends ChunkGenerator {
Main plugin;
public WorldGen(Main instance){
    plugin = instance;
}
public Location getFixedSpawnLocation(World world, Random random){return new Location(world, 0, 0, 0);}
public List<BlockPopulator> getDefaultPopulators(World world) {
    return new ArrayList<BlockPopulator>();
}
public byte[][] generatorBlockSections(World world, Random random, int chunkX, int chunkY, BiomeGrid biomeGrid) {
    byte[][] result = new byte[256 / 16][];
    int x, y, z;
    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++){
        for (z = 0; z < 16; z++){
            for (y = 0; y <= 9; y++){
                setBlock(result, x, y, z, (byte) Material.STATIONARY_WATER.getId());
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
@Override
public short[][] generateExtBlockSections(World world, Random random, int chunkX, int chunkY, BiomeGrid biomes){
    short[][] result = new short[256 / 16][];
    int x, y, z;

    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++){
        for (z = 0; z < 16; z++){
            for (y = 0; y <= 9; y++){
                setBlock(result, x, y, z, (short) Material.STATIONARY_WATER.getId());
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
private void setBlock(byte[][] result, int x, int y, int z, byte blockId) {
    if (result[y >> 4] == null){
        result[y >> 4] = new byte[4096];
    }
    result[y >> 4][((y & 0xF) << 8) | (z << 4) | x] = blockId;
}
private void setBlock(short[][] result, int x, int y, int z, short blockId) {
    if (result[y >> 4] == null){
        result[y >> 4] = new short[4096];
    }
    result[y >> 4][((y & 0xF) << 8) | (z << 4) | x] = blockId;
}
}
```

The End result was the basic flat world generation (as i have it set in  the server properties **should it be set to "Default"?) I still don't really understand how i would build a structure.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, like ChunkGenerator or BlockPopulator?

Comment: @xTrollxDudex I added what I have tried and am having no results with it, and i still don't know how I would build a structure with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bukkit.yml file, make sure to add the following:

```
worlds:
  world:
    generator: ExamplePlugin
```

Replace "world" with the name of your world and "ExamplePlugin" with the name of your plugin. There's a pretty good tutorial series at http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/the-always-up-to-date-definitive-guide-to-terrain-generation-part-one-prerequisites-and-setup.93982/. To build custom structures, you will need to create an extension of BlockPopulator, in which you will override the populate() method to be something like this:

```
public void populate(World world, Random rand, Chunk chunk) {
    chunk.getBlockAt(0, 64, 0).setType(Material.STONE);
}
```

This will set block (0, 64, 0) in each chunk to stone. To make lines of blocks, use for-loops. To make rectangles or cuboids, use nested for-loops. World generation gets complicated fast, which is why I would recommend looking into tutorials like the one above.